# SQLServer selecting from string specific words which match pattern

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a little problem :

Having table like `(id, title, text)` with text data like `2132-12-42 trash trash 2130-10-21 trash trash` etc...

What I'm trying to achieve is to select from text column only dates which is:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
```

So far I managed to list dates without rest of the string.. but only first date:

```
SELECT *,
SUBSTRING([text],NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', [text]),0),10) AS [date]
FROM table
```

So in provided example in column [date] it would display `2132-12-42` but will not show `2130-10-21`...

Is there any way to select all words with matching pattern not just first one?

I'm using Sql Server 2012.

Comment: In your `SUBSTRING` you're telling to select only 10 symbols from the begining of your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code selects all dates by your pattern from a given string:

```
DECLARE @IND INT
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Str = '2132-12-42 trash trash 2130-10-21 trash trash'

SET @IND = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Str)

WHILE(@IND > 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, @IND,  10)

    SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, @IND+11,  LEN(@Str))

    SET @IND = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @Str)

END
```

Comment: Yes it does works pretty nicely thanks, but is there a way to modify it so it takes data from rows in table not defined string? From table articles and column [text] for example

Comment: Use dynamic SQL something like `SET @Str = (SELECT text  FROM articles WHERE expression)`

Comment: You could probably select all the dates from the table by using a recursive common table expression

Comment: Well tried but seems like @Str in SUBSTRING and PATINDEX needs to be scalar variable as it seems so cant pass several rows directly through variable (changed it to table variable so it can hold more rows actually)

Comment: You might consider creating a stored procedure from my code and call it for every row in your SELECT statment

Comment: Ok solved as suggested by AndLev altho without stored procedure (possible also). Added also temp table which saves all results so they can be displayed as a single result set not multiple of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a recursive Common table expression to get all the dates out of all the rows:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(id INT, title NVARCHAR(255), [text] NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @table
        ( id, title, [text] ) VALUES  
        ( 1, 'test_1', '2132-12-22 blah blah blah some thing else 2130-10-21 something else etc 2010-05-06'),
        ( 2, 'test_2', 'blasdasdasdasda asdasdasd asdasdasd'),
        ( 3, 'test_3', 'blasdasdasdasda 2013-06-07 2015-01-01 asdasdasd asdasdasd')


;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT id, title, [text],
    SUBSTRING([text],NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', [text]),0),10) AS [date],
    SUBSTRING([text],NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', [text]),0)+10,LEN([text])) AS [rest],
    1 AS dateNum
FROM @table
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', [text]) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title, [text], 
    SUBSTRING(rest,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', rest),0),10) AS [date],
    SUBSTRING(rest,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', rest),0)+10,LEN(rest)) AS [rest],
    dateNum + 1 AS dateNum
FROM cte
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', rest) > 0
)
SELECT id, title , [date], dateNum, [text] FROM cte
```

AS you can see its pretty much your original query, but it just keeps track of the remainder for every iteration, and queries inside the remainder.

Seems to work correctly as far as I can tell...

results:

```
id  title   date    dateNum text
1   test_1  2132-12-22  1   2132-12-22 blah blah blah some thing else 2130-10-21 something else etc 2010-05-06
3   test_3  2013-06-07  1   blasdasdasdasda 2013-06-07 2015-01-01 asdasdasd asdasdasd
3   test_3  2015-01-01  2   blasdasdasdasda 2013-06-07 2015-01-01 asdasdasd asdasdasd
1   test_1  2130-10-21  2   2132-12-22 blah blah blah some thing else 2130-10-21 something else etc 2010-05-06
1   test_1  2010-05-06  3   2132-12-22 blah blah blah some thing else 2130-10-21 something else etc 2010-05-06
```